# DandelionServlet is not being invoked

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dandelion

Here is my problem. I'm trying to setup dandelion datatable on my Spring-boot Thymeleaf application. I believe I have everything wired correctly. I can take the javascript file from the `AssetCacheManger` that's in the logs and manually invoke the `DandelionServlet` from the URL, but it is not being invoke automatically as in the examples on GitHub. Also note I have Spring Security installed. Before posting I disabled security to make sure that wasn't an issue.

**POM**

`<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
     <artifactId>datatables-thymeleaf</artifactId>
     <version>0.10.0</version>
 </dependency>`

**JavaConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class DandelionConfig
{
    @Bean
    public DandelionDialect dandelionDialect()
    {
        return new DandelionDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataTablesDialect dataTablesDialect()
    {
         return new DataTablesDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean dandelionFilterRegistrationBean()
    {
         FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
         DandelionFilter dandelionFilter = new DandelionFilter();
         filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(dandelionFilter);
         return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dandelionServletRegistrationBean()
    {
         ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
         DandelionServlet dandelionServlet = new DandelionServlet();
         servletRegistrationBean.setServlet(dandelionServlet);
         servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/dandelion-assets/*");
         return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
 }
```

Here is the log portion that differs from the GitHub examples. No location found for delegate on AssetMapper

```
2015-06-17 12:57:51,503 Application: LMI [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.configuration.DatatablesConfigurator - Initializing the Javascript generator...
2015-06-17 12:57:51,508 Application: LMI [http-apr-8080-exec-7] WARN  com.github.dandelion.core.asset.AssetMapper - No location found for delegate on AssetStorageUnit [name=dandelion-datatables, version=0.10.0, type=js, dom=null, locations={delegate=dandelion-datatables.js}, attributes=null, attributesOnlyName=[]]
2015-06-17 12:57:51,513 Application: LMI [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.github.dandelion.core.asset.cache.AssetCacheManager - Retrieving asset with the key 591a4c961431b5fb3c6eedecfc5cca1b6ea5b09d/dandelion-datatables-0.10.0.js
2015-06-17 12:57:51,513 Application: LMI [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.github.dandelion.core.asset.cache.AssetCacheManager - Storing asset under the key 591a4c961431b5fb3c6eedecfc5cca1b6ea5b09d/dandelion-datatables-0.10.0.js
2015-06-17 12:57:51,518 Application: LMI [http-apr-8080-exec-7] WARN  com.github.dandelion.core.asset.AssetMapper - No location found for delegate on AssetStorageUnit [name=dandelion-datatables, version=0.10.0, type=js, dom=null, locations={delegate=dandelion-datatables.js}, attributes=null, attributesOnlyName=[]]
2015-06-17 12:57:51,518 Application: LMI [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.github.dandelion.core.asset.cache.AssetCacheManager - Retrieving asset with the key 591a4c961431b5fb3c6eedecfc5cca1b6ea5b09d/dandelion-datatables-0.10.0.js
2015-06-17 12:57:51,518 Application: LMI [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.github.dandelion.core.asset.cache.AssetCacheManager - Storing asset under the key 591a4c961431b5fb3c6eedecfc5cca1b6ea5b09d/dandelion-datatables-0.10.0.js
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple Spring Boot application using Thymeleaf and Dandelion-datatables.

You can get the code here https://github.com/ohiocowboy/datatable-thymeleaf-spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 0):

With reference to this answer

[Spring Boot + Thymeleaf + Dandelion configuration not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702563/spring-boot-thymeleaf-dandelion-configuration-not-working/28705332#28705332)

---

Can you use this **config** instead

```
@Configuration
public class DandelionConfig {

    @Bean
    public DandelionDialect dandelionDialect() {
        return new DandelionDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataTablesDialect dataTablesDialect(){
        return new DataTablesDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter dandelionFilter() {
        return new DandelionFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dandelionServletRegistrationBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new DandelionServlet(), "/dandelion-assets/*");
    }
}
```

along with these **dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatables-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatables-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```